# How do I customize the ResetPasswordForm in Django-AllAuth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm running into a couple of issues. Firstly, from the [configuration section of the docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html)...

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS (={})
Used to override forms, for example: {‘login’: ‘myapp.forms.LoginForm’}
```

How do I know what to put here?  I know it needs to be a (key, value) pair like `'password_reset_form':'myapp.forms.MyPasswordResetForm'` but how do I know the correct key to use?

Secondly, in my forms.py I tried to extend the [ResetPasswordForm](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py) like

```
from allauth.account.forms import ResetPasswordForm

class MyResetPasswordForm(ResetPasswordForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Override the email widget
        self.fields['email'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'email', 'required':'required', 'placeholder':'Email'})
```

but this keeps giving me the error `Error importing form class accounts.forms: "cannot import name 'ResetPasswordForm'"`

Any advice advice or direction on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember running into the first problem as well, and was surprised I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs! I ended up having to go through the [source code](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py) and the key value you need to put is in the views.py files in the `get_form_class` functions.

For your second question, at first glance I'm not sure why it's failing on the import - it works for me.

What version of all-auth are you using?

Comment: Spot on with the `get_form_class` advice.  I'm using version 0.19.0.  (At least, that's what it says when I run `pip freeze`.  I suspect there's some sort of circular dependency happening in my forms.py

Comment: Update: looks like it was a circular dependency (not sure where).  I copied my code for my custom PasswordResetForm into a forms2.py module and now everything works.

Comment: @Ben how did you do that? I copied only the import and the custom function to a new forms2.py, but I'm still getting the error. I have the allauth's latest version.

Comment: @Stratford the circular import most likely is caused between the settings and the form file. Your form doesn't need to extend the allauth ResetPasswordForm, it's enough with forms.Form (allauth will take care of everything else)

Answer (score 5):

Here is all the forms you can customize:

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'login': 'allauth.account.forms.LoginForm',
    'signup': 'allauth.account.forms.SignupForm',
    'add_email': 'allauth.account.forms.AddEmailForm',
    'change_password': 'allauth.account.forms.ChangePasswordForm',
    'set_password': 'allauth.account.forms.SetPasswordForm',
    'reset_password': 'allauth.account.forms.ResetPasswordForm',
    'reset_password_from_key': 
    'allauth.account.forms.ResetPasswordKeyForm',
    'disconnect': 'allauth.socialaccount.forms.DisconnectForm',
}
```

also, you can check the [docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html) to see for yourself.